# Load text file using command args

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-arguments, filepath

I am currently writing a text editor program, however I have run into a problem.

I am attempting to allow the user to open a file with my program by double-clicking it, which is achieved by setting the default program. I have been told that this sends the program the filepath as a command argument.
I am using it like this:

```
    private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        string filePath = args[1];
        addTab();
        getFontCollection();
        setFontSizes();
        getCurrentDocument.Text = (File.ReadAllText(filePath));

    }
```

However, I consistently get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.
```

If someone would please direct me to fixing this, it would be greatly appreciated.
By the way, the entire source code is located on Github, github.com/Criticaldiamonds/asys

**EDIT**

According to MSDN, the first argument is the program itself, followed by user-specified arguments. Therefore,

```
args[0] = the program
args[1] = "C:\users\Giovanni\Desktop\Hello.txt" (w/o quotes ofc)
```

Because the VS debugger escapes characters, the value of `args[1]` **in the debugger** is "C:\\users\\Giovanni\\Desktop\\Hello.txt"

Comment: Whatever data was in args[1] does not represent a valid path.

Comment: Can you check what the strings value is through debugging?

Comment: @Ian The value is C:\\Users\\Giovanni\\Desktop\\Hello.txt Does it have to do with the double backslashes?

Comment: I guess. Path strings should have only one backslash, but an '@' sign infront of them. So in your case probably `@"C:\Users\Giovanni\Desktop\Hello.txt"`

Comment: Is the value really C:\\Users\\Giovanni\\Desktop\\Hello.txt, or are you seeing `"C:\\Users\\Giovanni\\Desktop\\Hello.txt"` in the debugger, because the debugger shows C# strings with metacharacters like \ escaped with \\, so the string A\B would be shown as `"A\\B"` in the debugger.

Comment: @DourHighArch It's in the debugger

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38644453/edit) your question to include all values of `args`. Please be careful when copying values from the debugger, either escape metacharacters like `"C:\\Users\\Giovanni\\Desktop\\Hello.txt"` or don't, like `C:\Users\Giovanni\Desktop\Hello.txt`. Notice the quotes and doubled backslashes? They're important! Please do not mix these up or we can't understand your question.

Comment: @DourHighArch done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Methods on the [`System.IO.Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) Class

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    // using linq here reduces that array count check then extract
    var argPath = args.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(argPath))
    {
        // Your .LoadFile(...) method requires a full path
        var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(argPath);
        /* this part isn't needed unless you want to ensure the directory exists... but if it doesn't exist you can't open it anyway
        var dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
        if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
        */
        /* this isn't needed since you are using the full path
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dirPath);
        */ 
        addTab();
        getFontCollection();
        setFontSizes();
        getCurrentDocument.LoadFile(fullPath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
}
```

Comment: I _would_ use this, but i still am getting `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.`, so for now I will continue to use my version

Comment: what does the debugger say `fullPath` is set to?

Comment: In your example `dirPath + '\\' + fiuleName' should be the same as `Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(dirPath), Path.GetFileName(dirPath))`.  What does your command line look like?

Comment: Are you only sending a relative partial path to the command line?

Comment: I have been sending C:\users\Giovanni\Desktop\Hello.txt as a command line param in the VS debugger.

Comment: it's acting like a character is not encoded correctly.  On the debug property pane make sure the argument is wrapped in quotes (ascii quotes) and try it again.  (and make sure they are ascii quotes not matched titled quotes like you would get from copy/paste from office)

Comment: When I was looking around, it looked like it had something to do with the colon in the root directory `C:\`

Comment: that's just really weird as it shouldn't have any problem. but whateves if you have a working solution.

Comment: Yup! thats all that really matters in the end... Working first, optimization second

Comment: And guess what! your edit made it work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If GetFullPath fixed an already full path I'm going all in on some character was being encoded weird from the project file. Glad this fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem! Thank you to everyone who left comments, they really did help!
By messing around with directory settings, I ended up with the following code, which correctly loads the test file!

```
private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    string dirPath = args[1];
    string fileName = "";
    fileName = Path.GetFileName(dirPath);
    dirPath = dirPath.Substring(3);
    dirPath = Path.GetFullPath(dirPath);
    if (dirPath.Contains('\\')) dirPath = dirPath.Substring(0, dirPath.LastIndexOf('\\'));
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dirPath);
    addTab();
    getFontCollection();
    setFontSizes();
    getCurrentDocument.LoadFile(dirPath + '\\' + fileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
}
```

Comment: don't do this.  Use the `Path.Combine` functions.

Comment: @MatthewWhited for the dirPath + '\\' + fileName, line?

Comment: correct... but you don't even need it as that is the same as the original `dirPath`.  see my example

Comment: This doesn't make sense; `dirPath = dirPath.Substring(0, dirPath.LastIndexOf('\\'))` strips a trailing backslash, but `dirPath + '\\' + fileName` adds it back. The fact this code is different from that shown in your question makes me suspect something else is wrong. For example, where did `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dirPath)` come from? It's not in your original question.